# How to use a wordpress Database located on an other server

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I need to use a Database locating in an other server for my wordpress site

I changed this on my wp-config.php

```
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', '192.0.2.100');
```

and in the other computer I changed

Require local in phpmyadmin.conf to Rquire all granted in phpmyadmin.conf file
but still i get this error when i try to open my site

> Error connecting to the database

What should I do knowing tha im working on windows in both computers

Comment: are you trying in local, did you mean 192.0.2.100 is another computers address?

Comment: yeah im trying to use a database that exist in an other computer,by i mean by that adrees the @ Ip of that one

Answer (score 0):

change `define('DB_HOST', '192.0.2.100');` to `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');`

Comment: no at first it was define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');but i need to work with an other DB that exist on an other server not my localhost thats why i changed the host adrees

Comment: if you have cpanel then you can add server's IP Address which you can get in cpanel's dashboard

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll need the database host, name, username and password to connect to mysql and not only the host.

Furthermore, make sure the other server allows connecting to mysql remotely (check with your hosting provider). To verify you can use apps like [SequelPro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) to test the connection, and you'll need the following to connect:

1. Host: `database server IP`
2. Username: `database user`
3. Password: `database user password`
4. List item: `Database name (optional if you want to directly select it after successfully connecting)`

If you've successfully connected, you'll need to apply these setting in your wp-config.php file:

`/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'DB_NAME_USED ABOVE' );`

`/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'DB_USER_USED_ABOVE' );`

`/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'DB_PASS_USED_ABOVE' );`

`/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'DB_HOST_USED_ABOVE' );`

Cheers!

Comment: i did all this , the problem is that i can access to his database by  host adress/phpmyadmin but even that i changed the settings in  the wp-config.php file it always gives me this error "error establishing a database connection " when i try to  open my wordpress website

Comment: Phpmyadmin is hosted on the same server so doesn't count. Have you tried accessing from sequel pro?